# Usage of direct infinitive or bare infinitive

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

> 1) She did no more than sleep the whole day.    (Or)
>
> She did no more than sleeping the whole day

---

> 2) She did nothing but cry.     (Or)
>
> She did nothing but crying

which of  the sentences are correct in above pairs? What is the difference of meaning in those pairs?

Answer (score 1):

for the latter:

> She did nothing but cry
>   she was doing nothing but crying

Comment: Could you please explain the difference in meaning of your sentences

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda Excluding the difference in the tense, the sentence means that She just cried, in other words she did nothing except cry. the two first sentences are also the same meaning, i.e. She just slept the whole day.

Answer (score 1):

> She did no more than sleep the whole day. (Or)
> She did no more than sleeping the whole day

Neither of these is quite right although the first might be accepted by some people. It would be better to take the model of your other example.

> She did nothing but cry. (Or)
> She did nothing but crying

The first one here is correct, the other not. So for the first example

> She did nothing but sleep all day

would be much better.